# identify regular language

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

I'm quite lost in identifying regular language.

I know  that if R is a regular language then if A = RR, since is a concatenation of R therefore A is a regular language

But is B = {ww| w <- R} regular?

My first instinct was yes. Because it is also concatenation of R.. But since it is a subset of concatenation I feel I cannot prove it that way. Then I was thinking since w is a string of a regular language, which is a concatenation of singletons, then their concatenation... I get it that I'm quite off the track since if think that way, what isn't? now I'm more inclined to say it is not. Because I really cannot find a regular expression for it. I wanted to try using pumping lemma but it is really hard to apply to this example.

Can anyone offer some suggest? even a right track for me to follow would be great?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go ahead and try the pumping lemma.  Start with a really simple regular expression, for example:

```
R = ab*
```

Since at this point you are trying to prove that it is not regular, all you need is one counterexample.  So you can choose any *R* you'd like.  (The above will work fine.)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I've worked on it and can you just confirm my reasoning because I'm having doubts about it:
if R = ab* and w <- R,

B = {ww|w <-R} is not regular because if we assume it is, and p is the pumping length,
then (a^p)b(a^p)b <- B with length greater than p

By pumping lemma (a^p)b(a^p)b = xyz, with xy^iz in B for all i >= 0, since |xy| <=p
y consists entirely of 'a's. but then xyyz is not in D so it is a contradiction

Therefore it is not regular

Comment: Looks good to me (I had to review the pumping lemma, it's been a while...)